# Retrieve pointer to best match from overload set without calling

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, c++03

For various reasons I need to use 2 phase construction, furthermore the last phase is deferred and performed by another thread, some context:

```
...
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n) \
        template < typename ConnectionType, BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(n, typename T) > \
        boost::shared_ptr< ConnectionType > Connect( BOOST_PP_ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS(n, T, arg) ) \
        { \
            boost::shared_ptr< ConnectionType > con( boost::make_shared< ConnectionType >() ); \
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock sl( m_AddNetworkJobMutex ); \
            m_NetworkJobs.push_back( boost::bind( static_cast< void ( ConnectionType::* )( BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(n,T) ) >( &ConnectionType::Init ), con, BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(n, arg) ) ); \
            return con; \
        } 

#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS (1, 5)
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()
...
```

The problem here is that I want to select the best match possible from the overload set for ConnectionType::Init, but the cast is distinct and can't find a perfect match even if some of the arguments are convertible. So the questions becomes: Is it possible to somehow get the type & pointer to the best match from the overload set without actually calling it? Can't use anything which isn't available in C++03.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage lazy evaluation expression templates.

AFAIK bind expressions are precisely in that family (as are Boost Proto epxressions, Spirit Grammar parse expressions etc.).

**Update** finally got my act together. However, it only works with callable objects with *overloaded operator()*. I suppose you can use something like this as glue?

- I now show both C++03 and C++11 proofs-of-concept that might help get something of a glue functor built-up around this
- The C++03 is *near* equivalent (see the `// TODO` in the code)
- The C++03 version depends on Boost Typeof and Boost Bind (see [Boost Utility doc for `result_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#result_of) for backgrounds on result types of polymorphic function objects)
- Both versions live on IdeOne

#### C++03 (live on https://ideone.com/VHcEC)

Here is a partial port of the C++11 demo (below) into C++03 + Boost:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>

struct overloaded
{
    typedef int result_type;

    int operator()(const std::string& s) const { return 1; }
    int operator()(double d)             const { return 2; }
};

struct factory
{
    template <typename T> struct result { typedef BOOST_TYPEOF_TPL(boost::bind(overloaded(), T())) type; };

    template <typename T>
    typename result<T>::type operator()(const T& t) const 
    {
        return boost::bind(overloaded(), t);
    }
};

int main()
{
    overloaded foo;

    // based on local bind expression:
    BOOST_AUTO(unresolved, boost::bind(foo, _1));
    std::cout << unresolved("3.14") << std::endl;  // should print 1
    std::cout << unresolved(3.14)   << std::endl;  // should print 2

    // based on a factory function template
    factory makefoo;
    std::string str("3.14"); // TODO get rid of this explicit instanciation?
    std::cout << makefoo(str)() << std::endl;  // should print 1
    std::cout << makefoo(3.14)()   << std::endl;  // should print 2
}
```

#### C++11 (live on https://ideone.com/JILEA)

As a simple example, this should work alright:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std::placeholders;

struct overloaded
{
    int operator()(const std::string& s) const { return 1; }
    int operator()(double d)             const { return 2; }
};

template <typename T>
auto makefoo(const T& t) -> decltype(std::bind(overloaded(), t))
{
    return std::bind(overloaded(), t);
}

int main()
{
    overloaded foo;

    // based on local bind expression:
    auto unresolved = std::bind(foo, _1);
    std::cout << unresolved(3.14)   << std::endl;  // should print 2
    std::cout << unresolved("3.14") << std::endl;  // should print 1

    // based on a factory function template
    std::cout << makefoo(3.14)()   << std::endl;  // should print 2
    std::cout << makefoo("3.14")() << std::endl;  // should print 1
}
```

Comment: Cool, I'll be taking a look and see if I can get it to work, have an up vote now and an approve as soon as I see if it works :)

Comment: Darn just spotted the `c++03` tag. Will try to get this working with the famous BOOST_AUTO() macro

Comment: Partially ported to c++03/Boost now. Still working on the factory polymorphic functor :) **Edit** - only one explicit cast left to conquer (see `// TODO`)

Comment: One last quip: the `//TODO` for c++03 can be lifted by passing `T` into `factory` (instead of `const T&`). I won't recommend this as it has (performance) drawbacks (see http://ideone.com/VHcEC)